# Check if an XML file exists then change URLs in it

Tags: vbscript

This is my first VBScript I have ever written and I would like to know if there is any obvious blunders in the code. All the code should do is check if file exists then change the Yahoo URL to the Google URL in the XML file. Note: The code seems to function properly.

```
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If (objFSO.FileExists("C:\urlsinfo.xml")) Then
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8

Dim textToReplace
Dim textReplacement
textToReplace = "http://www.yahoo.com"
textReplacement = "http://www.google.com"

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\urlsinfo.xml", ForReading)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, textToReplace, textReplacement)

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\urlsinfo.xml", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
WScript.Quit()

Else
Dim errorFileSys, errorLogTxt

Set errorFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set errorLogTxt = errorFileSys.OpenTextFile("C:\urlsinfoError.log", ForAppending, True) 
errorLogTxt.WriteLine(Now &"     urlsinfo.xml file did not exist in directory C:\. ")
errorLogTxt.Close

WScript.Quit()
End If

'Exit Script
WScript.Quit()
```

Comment: This isn’t an answer but I *strongly* suggest you drop VBScript, which is old, unmaintained and a horrible, hacky mess, and use a modern scripting language (such as Python) instead. Even at the height of its usage VBS was *never* very good and since there are now tools to replace it, there’s simply no use-case where it’s ever appropriate. The last version of VBS was released over 10 years ago, before .NET came out.

Comment: `C:\urlsinfo.xml` should be a named constant. It occurs multiple times in the code.

Answer (score 6):

I reworked your VBScript a bit with comments, see below. In response to the comment from Konrad, I can agree with him for 90% of the cases. VBScript stays interesting for system management, logon scripts, etc., but I myself am replacing it with Ruby which isn't a big step up from VBScript, and on the other hand it has almost all the goodies from python. If you want to compare, take a look at e.g. http://yagni.com/rosetta-stone/#0 (what happened to https://rosettacode.org/ ?). You'll see that the Ruby code is most of the time the smallest and the most comprehensible.

The adapted VBScript version:

```
Option explicit 'always use this
'declarations first, be concise
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8, CreateIfNeeded = true
Dim objFSO, objFile, textToReplace, textReplacement, strNewText, strText
Dim errorFileSys, errorLogTxt, urlsinfo
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FileExists(urlsinfo) Then 'indent
  textToReplace   = "http://www.yahoo.com"
  textReplacement = "http://www.google.com"
  urlsinfo = "C:\urlsinfo.xml"
  Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(urlsinfo, ForReading)
  strText = objFile.ReadAll
  objFile.Close
  strNewText = Replace(strText, textToReplace, textReplacement)
  Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(urlsinfo, ForWriting)
  objFile.WriteLine strNewText
  objFile.Close
Else
  Set errorFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set errorLogTxt = errorFileSys.OpenTextFile("C:\urlsinfoError.log", ForWriting, CreateIfNeeded) 
  errorLogTxt.WriteLine(Now &"     urlsinfo.xml file did not exist in directory C:\. ")
  errorLogTxt.Close
  Wscript.Quit 1 'you could use quit here to give an errorlevel back to the OS
End If

'Exit Script 'no need for obvious comments
'WScript.Quit() 'no need for this at the end of the script
'also quit is a sub, no need for the ()
```

And the same script in Ruby:

```
urlsinfo, urlsinfoError = "C:/urlsinfo.xml", "c:/urlsinfoError.log"
textToReplace, textReplacement = "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.google.com"

begin
  File.write(urlsinfo, File.read(urlsinfo).gsub(textToReplace, textReplacement))
rescue
  File.write(urlsinfoError, "#{Time.now}      urlsinfo.xml file did not exist in directory C:\. ")
end
```

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. Peter thanks for the rework. It definitely helps me understand how to approach the code in a much better way.Wow look at Ruby! 7 lines and done!

Comment: Hey are you still around?  we have a need for VBScript Programmers here on Code Review, I hope that you come back to CR. even if it is to tell me my code looks like crap

Comment: I know you said that you are writing in Ruby, we have several Ruby Questions,  I will eventually learn Ruby ( my cousin teaches it ) but I can only help with the logic as is right now.

Answer (score 6):

### Possible Error?

Another thing that I noticed is that you have not Declared `objFile` in your code??
I am not sure if you meant to do this or not, I haven't tested this code, but I left `objFile` alone because you do set it twice, for some reason I want to say that you should `Dim` and then `ReDim` that variable/object or **probably a better idea** create one for reading and another for writing.

---

1. you can't get away with not Indenting in Python or Ruby, and not indenting in any flavor of VB is really bad coding practice, it would be much different if the language used semi-colons or line terminators, but it doesn't so indentation helps everyone know where they are.
2. don't Declare variables inside of `If`'s, `For`'s or other blocks unless they are only going to be used inside that block and not carried to other parts of the code.

   - that means `Const ForAppending = 8` needs to be moved outside of the `If` Statement
   - all of those variables should be declared outside of that `If` Statement, especially the first 3 `ForReading` , `ForWriting`, and `ForAppending`
3. Joined Declaration and Assignment - you can assign these like this

   - `Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`
   - `Dim textToReplace : Set textToReplace = "http://www.yahoo.com"`
   - `Dim textReplacement : Set textReplacement = "http://www.google.com`
   - `Dim errorFileSys : Set errFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`
   - `Dim errorLogTxt : Set errorLogTxt = errorFileSys.OpenTextFile("C:\urlinforError.log",ForAppending, True)`
4. I am sure that you could use a `Try Catch` type of statement in there somewhere too.
5. it also looks like you could use a `Using` statement there for writing to your Error log, but I am not sure that VBScript can do that?
6. the last statement will never be reached, you don't need it.

   - `WScript.Quit()`
7. what palacsint said about the `C:\urlsinfo.xml` and that it should be a constant variable.

here is what it would look like after all but Items 4 & 5

---

```
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8
Const xmlInput = "C:\urlsinfo.xml"

Dim textToReplace : Set textToReplace = "http://www.yahoo.com"
Dim textReplacement : Set textReplacement = "http://www.google.com"


If (objFSO.FileExists(xmlInput)) Then

    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(xmlInput, ForReading)
    strText = objFile.ReadAll
    objFile.Close
    strNewText = Replace(strText, textToReplace, textReplacement)

    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(xmlInput, ForWriting)
    objFile.WriteLine strNewText
    objFile.Close
    WScript.Quit()

Else
    Dim errorFileSys : Set errorFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim errorLogTxt : Set errorLogTxt = errorFileSys.OpenTextFile("C:\urlsinfoError.log", ForAppending, True) 
    errorLogTxt.WriteLine(Now &"     urlsinfo.xml file did not exist in directory C:\. ")
    errorLogTxt.Close
    WScript.Quit()
End If
```

---

This is a little bit cleaner, I think that some Exception Handling could be added in there to make it a little nicer, maybe a `Try Catch` or the VBScript equivalent. I would also look into using the `Using` statement style code in VBScript, I know you can do it in VB but not sure about VBScript.

Comment: I only do maintenance with vbscript, new programs are in Ruby, if you see the example i posted you see why. No, vbscript has no using keyword or functionality and the error catching is poor, no try catch, you can set error skipping on with "on error resume next" but if you want to check if an error did occor you have to check every time with "if err.number <>0 then wscript.echo err.description", so it is not very usable

Comment: @peter, I hear what you are saying,  I use VBScript for Writing tokens inside a 3rd party application,  and it's a pain, right now I have a token that works in stage but not in production, can't figure it out, yet.